# Compare two arrays of dictionaries and add/remove items

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have two arrays of dictionaries like this

```
  arrCurrent = [{
        id = 1;
        name = "Name1";
    },{
        id = 2;
        name = "Name2";
    },{
        id = 3;
        name = "Name3";
    }];


    arrUpdated = [{
        id = 1;
        name = "Name1 has changed";
    },{
        id = 2;
        name = "Name2 has changed";
    },{
        id = 4;
        name = "Name4 is a new item";
    }];
```

My requirement is to merge these two arrays according to following conditions

1) If arrUpdated contains new items(item with new **id**) it should be added as a new item.

2) If arrUpdated contains items with the same **id** of arrCurrent contains, those items should be replaced with the updated items

So, the final array should be like this

```
arrFinal = [{
        id = 1;
        name = "Name1 has changed";
    },{
        id = 2;
        name = "Name2 has changed";
    },{
        id = 3;
        name = "Name3";
    },{
        id = 4;
        name = "Name4 is a new item";
    }];
```

Hopes my requirement is clear, whats is the best way to do this?

This is how I am trying to do it. But this methods get duplicate items. Also, looping through arrays is not the best way

Please note: actual code contains different names to above mentioned array names. But same logic

arrSavedSectors = arrCurrent

arrAllUpdatedSectors = arrUpdated

arrFilteredSectors = arrFinal

```
NSMutableArray *arrSavedSectors = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:  [dictionary objectForKey:@"ArrSectors"]];
NSMutableArray *arrFilteredSectors = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:arrSavedSectors];

// add updated sectors to list
NSArray *arrAllUpdatedSectors = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[sectorDetails objectForKey:@"AllUpdatedSectors"]];

if([arrSavedSectors count] > 0){
    // check for updated sectors (Which are already saved in the plist, but recently updated some details)
    for(NSDictionary *dicSector in arrSavedSectors){
        for(NSDictionary *dicUpdatedSector in arrAllUpdatedSectors){
            if([[dicUpdatedSector objectForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:[dicSector objectForKey:@"id"]]){
                [arrFilteredSectors removeObject:dicSector];
                [arrFilteredSectors addObject:dicUpdatedSector];
            }
            else{
                [arrFilteredSectors addObject:dicUpdatedSector];
            }
        }

    }
}
else{
    [arrFilteredSectors addObjectsFromArray:arrAllUpdatedSectors];
}
```

Comment: Show the code you have so far.

Comment: Refer  vikingosegundo answer.That is the acceptable answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think a loop would do this.

```
   for(int x=0;x<[arrUpdate count];x++){
       //condition 2
        if([[arrCurrent valueForKey:@"id"] containsObject:[[arrUpdate objectAtIndex:x] valueForKey:@"id"]]){

       }
     //condition 1
      else{
         [arrCurrent addObject: [arrUpdate objectAtIndex:x]]

       }
    }
```

Though you could also use predicate.

I haven't tested this code for i do not have a machine. But you could at least modify this.

UPDATE:

i ended up finding a machine to prove that my code works. using the test data the asker provided:

```
NSMutableArray *arrCurrent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@{
    @"id":@"1", @"name":@"Name1"
},@{
    @"id":@"2", @"name":@"Name2"
},@{
    @"id":@"3", @"name":@"Name3"
}]];


NSMutableArray *arrUpdated = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@{
    @"id":@"1", @"name":@"Name1 has changed"
},@{
    @"id":@"2", @"name":@"Name2 has changed"
},@{
    @"id":@"4", @"name":@"Name4 is a new item"
}]];


for(int x=0;x<[arrUpdated count];x++){
    //condition 2
    if([[arrCurrent valueForKey:@"id"] containsObject:[[arrUpdated objectAtIndex:x] valueForKey:@"id"]]){

        //start updating current array
        for(int y=0;y<[arrCurrent count];y++){
            if([[[arrCurrent objectAtIndex:y] valueForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:[[arrUpdated objectAtIndex:x] valueForKey:@"id"]]){
                NSLog(@" (%@) will change to (%@)",[[arrCurrent objectAtIndex:y] valueForKey:@"name"],[[arrUpdated objectAtIndex:x] valueForKey:@"name"]);
                [arrCurrent replaceObjectAtIndex:y withObject:[arrUpdated objectAtIndex:x] ];
                break;
            }
        }


    }
    //condition 1
    else{
        [arrCurrent addObject: [arrUpdated objectAtIndex:x]];

    }
}
NSLog(@"RESULT>: %@",arrCurrent);
```

RESULT: >>

```
2015-06-04 23:24:30.949 dd[7523:60b]  (Name1) will change to (Name1 has changed)
    2015-06-04 23:24:30.950 dd[7523:60b]  (Name2) will change to (Name2 has changed)
    2015-06-04 23:24:30.951 dd[7523:60b] RESULT>: (
            {
            id = 1;
            name = "Name1 has changed";
        },
            {
            id = 2;
            name = "Name2 has changed";
        },
            {
            id = 3;
            name = Name3;
        },
            {
            id = 4;
            name = "Name4 is a new item";
        }
    )
```

Comment: This coding in not giving the answer.Please un tick otherwise minus mark will be given.The reults of this part is - (
        {
        id = 1;
        name = "Name1 has changed";
    },
        {
        id = 2;
        name = "Name2 has changed";
    },
        {
        id = 4;
        name = "Name4 is a new item";
    }
)

Comment: That's why i said I haven't tested it and let the asker modify it. Maybe he modified it and was able to get the right answer.

Comment: i have update my answer and used my previous code. And as you can see, it's perfectly working.

Comment: Downvoting my past answers because i proved you wrong? @ user3182143

Comment: one reason people might favour my code over yours: Yours is overly complex. ie you nest for loops with if and else statements. this means that for every call of either `for`, `if`, `else` or `break` a different execution path in your code evolves — increasing the complexity and with it the space for error. my code on the other hand uses only high-level abstractions. (in fact the only if statement is found in the wrapper init and is more conventional than a necessity). if you look at my last code block: no matter how you change the input arrays, the following code execution path stays the same.

Answer (score 2):

Time for some Set operations.

The hardest part is that we need to give the set we are using an understanding of objects being equal and identical.

None of the dictionary are, but we can introduce a wrapper class to use it's implementation for that.

```
@interface Wrapper : NSObject
@property NSDictionary *dictionary;
-(instancetype)initWithDictionary: (NSDictionary *)dict;
@end

@implementation Wrapper

-(instancetype)initWithDictionary: (NSDictionary *)dict
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.dictionary = dict;
    }
    return self;
}

-(BOOL)isEqual:(Wrapper *)object
{
    return [self.dictionary[@"id"] isEqual: object.dictionary[@"id"]];
}

-(NSUInteger)hash
{
    return [self.dictionary[@"id"] unsignedIntegerValue];
}

-(NSString *)description
{
    return [self.dictionary description];
}

@end
```

Now we can use it to wrap each dictionary

```
NSArray *arrCurrent = @[[[Wrapper alloc] initWithDictionary: @{@"id": @(1), @"name" : @"Name 1"}],
                        [[Wrapper alloc] initWithDictionary: @{@"id": @(2), @"name" : @"Name 2"}],
                        [[Wrapper alloc] initWithDictionary: @{@"id": @(3), @"name" : @"Name 3"}]];

NSArray *arrUpdated = @[[[Wrapper alloc] initWithDictionary: @{@"id": @(1), @"name" : @"Name 1 has Changed"}],
                        [[Wrapper alloc] initWithDictionary: @{@"id": @(2), @"name" : @"Name 2 has Changed"}],
                        [[Wrapper alloc] initWithDictionary: @{@"id": @(4), @"name" : @"Name 4"}]];
```

Next we create sets from this

```
NSSet *setCurrent = [NSSet setWithArray:arrCurrent];
NSSet *setUpdated = [NSSet setWithArray:arrUpdated];
```

and now we do the set arithmetics

```
NSMutableSet *setFinal = [setUpdated mutableCopy];
[setFinal unionSet:setCurrent];
```

finally we use key value coding to unwrap the dictionaries

```
NSArray *arrFinal = [setFinal valueForKey:@"dictionary"];
```

Result:

```
{(
    {
        id = 1;
        name = "Name 1 has Changed";
    },
        {
        id = 2;
        name = "Name 2 has Changed";
    },
        {
        id = 3;
        name = "Name 3";
    },
        {
        id = 4;
        name = "Name 4";
    }
)}
```

---

One problem with this code: The wrapper is not useful in other situations as the rules to determine equality might differ, so it would be useful to be able to define them when needed. We could do this with blocks:

The Wrapper becomes

```
@interface Wrapper : NSObject
@property id object;
@property (copy) BOOL (^equalComparator)(id a, id b);
@property (copy) NSUInteger (^hashBlock)(id a);
@end

@implementation Wrapper

-(instancetype)initWithObject: (id)obj
              equalComparator:(BOOL (^)(id a, id b))equalComparator
                    hashBlock:(NSUInteger (^)(id a))hashBlock
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.equalComparator = equalComparator;
        self.hashBlock = hashBlock;
        self.object = obj;
    }
    return self;
}

-(BOOL)isEqual:(Wrapper *)object
{
    return self.equalComparator(self.object, object.object);
}

-(NSUInteger)hash
{
    return self.hashBlock(self.object);
}

-(NSString *)description
{
    return [self.object description];
}

@end
```

and we use it like

```
BOOL (^eq)(NSDictionary *a, NSDictionary *b) = ^(NSDictionary *a, NSDictionary *b){
    return [a[@"id"] isEqual: b[@"id"]];
};

NSUInteger (^hash)(NSDictionary *a) = ^(NSDictionary *a){
    return [a[@"id"] unsignedIntegerValue];
};

NSArray *arrCurrent = @[[[Wrapper alloc] initWithObject: @{@"id": @(1), @"name" : @"Name 1"} equalComparator:eq hashBlock:hash],
                        [[Wrapper alloc] initWithObject: @{@"id": @(2), @"name" : @"Name 2"} equalComparator:eq hashBlock:hash],
                        [[Wrapper alloc] initWithObject: @{@"id": @(3), @"name" : @"Name 3"} equalComparator:eq hashBlock:hash]];

NSArray *arrUpdated = @[[[Wrapper alloc] initWithObject: @{@"id": @(1), @"name" : @"Name 1 has Changed"} equalComparator:eq hashBlock:hash],
                        [[Wrapper alloc] initWithObject: @{@"id": @(2), @"name" : @"Name 2 has Changed"} equalComparator:eq hashBlock:hash],
                        [[Wrapper alloc] initWithObject: @{@"id": @(4), @"name" : @"Name 4"} equalComparator:eq hashBlock:hash]];

NSSet *setCurrent = [NSSet setWithArray:arrCurrent];
NSSet *setUpdated = [NSSet setWithArray:arrUpdated];
NSMutableSet *setFinal = [setUpdated mutableCopy];
[setFinal unionSet:setCurrent];

NSArray *arrFinal = [setFinal valueForKey:@"object"];
```